# Running sql BCP bash file from crontab

Tags: linux, cron, bcp

i have 1 bash file which contain bcp query call .
bash file contain

```
echo "runnig bcp file"
#!/bin/bash
timelogpath="/home/bcp_project/bcp_cron_job/test_cron_job"

dbName="**" 
ServerName="***"
UserName="***"
Password="****"
ldate=`date +%d-%m-%y_%H_%M_%S`

bcp "SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(23),getutcdate(), 121)" queryout '/home/bcp_project/bcp_cron_job/test_cron_job/BCPNextRunTime.txt' -t","  -S $ServerName -U $UserName -P $Password  -c   -C 65001

echo $ldate>$timelogpath"/Datalog.txt"
```

its work fine if we running this bash file using below command .

```
bash cron_job.sh -- run
```

but when i am setting this in cron tab, its not able to create BCPNextRunTime.txt.
but its able to create Datalog.txt and put time on this.
so its somewhere not able to run bcp file.

i have this in my cron tab

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/bin/sh:/home/bcp_project/bcp_cron_job/test_cron_job:/opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp
MAILTO=""

*/1 * * * * /bin/sh /home/bcp_project/bcp_cron_job/test_cron_job/cron_job.sh > /home/bcp_project/bcp_cron_job/test_cron_job/change_bcp.log
```

and required access provided by

```
chmod u+x cron_job.sh
```

i am running this as super user currently.

Answer (score 1):

- Shebang `#!` should be first 2 character of a script file and the file should have Unix line endings `\n`.
- Expanded variables should be quoted when substituted in the command line as `"${varname}"`.
- `/bin/sh` and `/bin/bash` are very different (although implemented with the same software), so pick either one or the other.
- Production bash scripts should have `set -e -u -o pipefail` as a second line after the shebang, then they will fail on the first problem.

Next step after addressing the above, I would crontab it as `/bin/bash -x /path/to/script.sh > /path/to/logfile.log 2>&1` and see what comes out.

Comment: hi thanks ,  /bin/bash -x /path/to/script.sh > /path/to/logfile.log 2>&1  this help , came to know not able to find bcp .  bcz i did mistake  /opt/mssql-tools/bin/bcp . now working fine after changing above to this  /opt/mssql-tools/bin